# Buttercup desktop won't authenticate google drive

Tags: authentication

Ubuntu 20.04. Buttercup (Buttercup-linux-x86_64.AppImage). Open it, click on add a vault, select google drive, click Authenticate, new web page opens (in Chrome), I input my credential, continue, a new web page opens at Buttercup.pw saying "Authenticated. You can close this window now." I close it.

The problem is that the desktop version still displays the same page about adding a vault and to click "Authenticate or Cancel". The info about the successful authentication done with the browser, was not received by to the desktop version. I've tried with Firefox, I've tried with a different PC also running Ubuntu 20.04. Still not working.

Comment: Hello. It seems you issues are with this app not with the OS. Have you checked on the 91 know issues on the Buttercup page? https://github.com/buttercup/buttercup-desktop/releases

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Hi, have you had any luck since?